# How to get a nullable DateTime value?

Tags: powershell, sqlite

My SQLite database contains a nullable DateTime field that I have to read in PowerShell. My `select` query:

```
$colId = "myPrimaryKeyColumn"
$col1 = "myColumnName"
$select = "SELECT CAST($col1 as nvarchar(20)) FROM $table ORDER BY $colId DESC LIMIT 1"
```

Which returns `CAST(Alive as nvarchar(20)) : 04/11/2022 17:17:15`. How to get just the `04/11/2022 17:17:15` part?

I tried :

```
Invoke-SqliteQuery -SQLiteConnection $con -Query $select | Where-Object { $_.$col1}
Invoke-SqliteQuery -SQLiteConnection $con -Query $select -As DataRow | Where-Object { $_.$col1}
Invoke-SqliteQuery -SQLiteConnection $con -Query $select -As PSObject| Where-Object { $_.$col1}
```

Which prints just an empty line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `-As SingleValue` (you don't need `Where-Object`)

```
Invoke-SqliteQuery -SQLiteConnection $con -Query $select -As SingleValue
```

Comment: I did `$res = Invoke-SqliteQuery -SQLiteConnection $con -Query $select -As SingleValue` and my data looks like `04/11/2022 17:17:15` but `$res -is [DateTime]` is always false, do you know why?

Comment: Your data is always a string. If you want a [Datetime] object you need to convert it using Get-Date. But if you just want to check if it is NULL or empty, you can test it as you would with a string.